# Using UserManager.FindAsync with a custom UserStore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I have implemented a custom `UserStore`, it implements `IUserStore<DatabaseLogin, int>` and `IUserPasswordStore<DatabaseLogin, int>`.

My Login action method is as below:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (Authentication.Login(user.Username, user.Password))
    {
        DatabaseLogin x = await UserManager.FindAsync(user.Username, user.Password);
        DatabaseLogin Login = Authentication.FindByName(user.Username);
        if (Login != null)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity ident = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(Login,
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            AuthManager.SignOut();
            AuthManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = false
            }, ident);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login");
    }
}
return View();
```

In the custom authentication class that I wrote, `Authentication`, I have a Login method that works fine, also `FindByName` method returns an app user. But if I try to `SignIn` with that login, the user isn't recognized as authenticated and `HttpContext.User.Identity` is always null, so I imagine that I have to try `UserManager.FindAsync`.

This method calls `FindByNameAsync` and `GetPasswordHashAsync`, and it always return null.

```
public Task<DatabaseLogin> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
    return Task.FromResult<DatabaseLogin>(Authentication.FindByName(userName));
}

public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(DatabaseLogin user)
{
    if (user == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    return Task.FromResult<string>(user.Password);
}
```

And the `Authentication.FindByName`

```
public static DatabaseLogin FindByName(string name)
{
    string GetUserQuery = string.Format(
        "USE db;SELECT principal_id AS id, name as userName, create_date AS CreateDate, modify_date AS modifyDate FROM sys.database_principals WHERE type='S' AND authentication_type = 1 AND name = '{0}'"
        , name);
    DatabaseLogin user;
    using (var db = new EFDbContext())
    {
        user = db.Database.SqlQuery<DatabaseLogin>(GetUserQuery).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    user.Password = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("pass"));
    return user;
}
```

As you can see I'm using database users, I'm not sure how I can retrieve a hashed password for them. For now, I'm just storing the Base65 of the correct password!

I have no idea where I'm going wrong, any guidance is welcome.

Comment: Could you please transfer your answer out of your question and to a proper SO answer? You can answer yourself. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: nothing's wrong. User is authenticated in other action methods, but apparently not in the current action method.

This is the process that I followed, maybe it will help you debug your app.

After reading the [source code](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs), `FindAsync` first calls `FindByNameAsync`, followed by `CheckPasswordAsync` which references `VerifyPasswordAsync`. So it should be fine If I could override `VerifyPasswordAsync`.

I created a custom `password hasher` that implements `IPasswordHasher`, and registered it in the `create` method of my `UserManager` like this:

```
manager.PasswordHasher = new DbPasswordHasher();
```

So by now, I can get my user from `UserManager.FindAsync`, but it turned out that it doesn't matter where you get the user since `HttpContext.User.Identity` is still null! My mistake was that I didn't notice the user isn't authenticated in the current action, in other action methods it works as expected!

Comment: That worked for me as well, i've tried everything until find your sugestion, after implement a IPasswordHasher i got it working... thank you very much!